# Full Screen / Maximize Top Edge Action only works on main monitor (Dual Monitor Setup) Compiz

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, compiz, multiple-monitors

Certain applications that I have (terminal, NVIDIA XServer settings, and a few others) will go full screen properly-that is, whatever monitor I am viewing the application window in, if I drag it up to go full screen, it will go full screen in *that* monitor. A few other ones, however (Chrome, Thunderbird), when I am in my secondary monitor, and I drag the window up to go full screen, it resizes the window to full screen in the *other* monitor, my main one. What is going on here? My xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@allspice)  Wed Dec 18 09:07:35 UTC 2013


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "NEC LCD1960NXi"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 770"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-       auto-select +1280+62"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I've read answers about Flash player problems, but that is not applicable to me. I also downloaded CompizConfig Settings Manager, but didn't see anything in there.

Thanks in advance!